# Added UIBarButtonItem is not displayed in the app until touching its hit area

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

Using Xcode 5.1, I have created a View Controller and embedded it via Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller. I then proceeded to add to its toolbar a UIBarButtonItem by dragging it in Storyboard.

When I run the app, I do not see the button. However, if I click where the button is supposed to be - only then do I see it.

What could cause this odd behavior?

Comment: Could you show your code for adding the barbuttonitem?

Comment: I should mention I add it by dragging it to the toolbar via the storyboard.

Comment: I will provide the project shortly. Also, note that this is not your typical iOS project. It is based on the Worklight framework, but by the time it reaches the view controller it is all native.

Comment: I don't think that has to do with it, have you tried adding your BarButtonItem in the viewDidLoad method of your ViewController? Or is it not a left/right button and in a different location?

Comment: I did not. I have added the project. To see the issue, run the app and click on the "open..." button. This will present the aforementioned view controller.

Comment: I couldn't see an "open..." button when running your app, but I would highly suggest just adding the button through code, unless you have some specific UI you want on it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "add...". Then, on the top-right corner is where the button is supposed to be.

Comment: The button that says "Item"? I see it immediately...which version of Xcode are you running?

Comment: I tried in both latest Xcode 5.1 and Xcode 6 beta 5.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59346/discussion-between-bhendricks-and-idan-adar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the tintColor is not being initialized through the storyboard. To make the button show up immediately, simply do:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = self.view.tintColor;
```

in viewDidLoad, and the button will be initialized with the right color. 
Seems like an Xcode bug.